# Google Workspaces setup support email address

Tags: email, google-workspace

I don't know how to set up my company's email system. We are using Google Workspaces and want to solve the following problem:

1. Send email as info@mycompany.com from our webshop
2. Send email as info@mycompany.com manually
3. Receive email at info@mycompany.com in a way so many people at the company can see it.

1 & 2 can be solved by creating an email alias for an existing user called info@ and using that email account and alias.

3 can be solved by creating a Google Group under the email info@mycompany.com which would receive email and allow everyone to see it. It even has nice features like ticking off emails and assigning them to people. However it's not possible to send email from the group email address :(

So I'm stuck here. Thinking that maybe I should use a different email provider for this like we already use MailChimp for mass emailing. Not sure how that would play with the user emails that have to be managed by Google Workspaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Group option should work for all scenarios as long as your webshop supports using SMTP relay without authentication. In this case, you can connect from any email address from your domain using smtp-relay.gmail.com on port 25 using the webshop IP address as the main authentication method. See the "Only addresses in my domains" option at  https://support.google.com/a/answer/2956491?hl=en

You can also send messages from Groups either from the Groups UI or from any of the members inbox as long as you configure the [send mail as feature](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/22370?hl=en).

Comment: This indeed sounds like it would cover all the scenarios. Thank you for the answer. In the meanwhile I looked at tools like Freshdesk to handle customer support emails, so I'll decide between that and setting up Google Workspaces as you described.